# "Вот теперь понятно"

Tags: запятые

Ставится ли запятая после "теперь"?

Comment: Нет, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая в этом месте невозможна, но заслуживает внимания "авторское" *тире*. Помимо обозначения возможной риторической паузы, оно заместило бы опущенное уточнение: когда вы раскрыли важную подробность и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью зависит от желания автора и, соответственно, смысла высказывания.

**Вот** -- восклицательная, указательная, усилительная либо положительная частица, смысл которой, как Вы уже, наверное, поняли, может быть очень разнообразным, что зависит от её значения.

Наш случай может быть т̶р̶а̶к̶т̶о̶в̶а̶н̶  всеми способами, приведёнными выше, кроме указательного значения:

**Вот, теперь понятно!** либо **Вот! Теперь понятно!**

Здесь частица имеет восклицательное значение.

**Вот (равносильно "да"), теперь понятно**.

Здесь "вот" имеет утвердительный смысл.

**Вот теперь понятно**.

Здесь слово "вот" усиливает указательное местоимение "теперь".

Надеюсь, помог разобраться.

Comment: Вопрос про запятую после "теперь", а не после "вот".

Answer (score 1):

В Интернете нашлость похожее предложение: "Вот теперь — профессионально, благодарю за позитив".

Запятую в заданном предложении нельзя поставить, но можно, как мне кажется,  поставить авторское тире, если нужно подчеркнуть слово "теперь".

Тогда получится: *Вот теперь — понятно.*